# Sort transformation is taking huge time in SSIS. Is there a way to remove duplicates without using the Sort Transformations?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

My SSIS package is taking huge time. When I checked Sort is taking time. From some artcles in the web also I came to know that the Sort is really an expensive operation. Is there any other option to remove duplicates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your source? If you can remove dups or sort from source, it would be optimal.

Comment: My source is SQL server. will that be Ok if I use a conditional split to remove the duplicate rows.

Comment: There are a few ways with SQL server. 1. Straight use a group by or distinct. 2. use row_number to partition the data and then use conditional split to keep just rn = 1

Comment: those were two different options. 1. Is if you don't need all the source data for something else. 2. the source data is part of an aggregate that you are sending down 2 different paths. i.e. sale of an item for $100 is recorded 5x. you may want to know a list of items you ever sold or you may want to also know the grand total of sales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the data to a staging table, and then remove the duplicates with TSQL while moving it to your final destination table.

Or if your data source is a SQL Query, modify the query to remove the duplicates.